# Mixed content error, but url is Https?

Tags: firefox, https, analytics, mixed-content, double-click-advertising

With the latest Firefox update (48.0.2), we are seeing mixed content errors from our doubleclick tags on our HTTPS site, however the error is not making any sense to me because the offending URL seems to use https:

Blocked loading mixed active content "about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=https%3A//fls.doubleclick.net%3Bsrc%3D3268620%3Btype%3Dboo120%3Bcat%3D3-c420%3Bord%3D1/%3F&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20find%20the%20server%20at%20fls.doubleclick.net%3Bsrc%3D3268620%3Btype%3Dboo120%3Bcat%3D3-c420%3Bord%3D1."[Learn More]

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Maybe even though the document itself is served from an `https` URL, it contains stylesheets or scripts or images with `http` URLs. You checked the error console to see if any more specific messages are getting logged there?

Comment: I did - unfortunately this is the only error displayed.